# AppleScript to set up VPN on Mac 10.8 is loosing focus and types text in wrong window, what is wrong?

Tags: macos, focus, applescript, osx-mountain-lion, vpn

I wanted to share a very useful AppleScript with other Mac admins but it is losing focus. When it's run in AppleScript editor it runs to a certain stage and then instead of copying text to required windows it replaces text in AppleScript editor. Can anyone suggest why?

```
set vpnname to "VPN (Primary)"
set vpnserver to "vpn.website.com"
set vpnsecret to "abcdefghij"
set vpnusername to system attribute "USER"
set groupname to "GROUP"

activate application "System Preferences"
tell application "System Events"

    -- Checks whether Universal Access is enabled - this is required for all scripts to work
    if not (UI elements enabled) then
        tell application "System Preferences"
            activate
            set current pane to pane id "com.apple.preference.universalaccess"
            display dialog "This script requires access for assistive devices be enabled." & return & return & "To continue, click the OK button and enter an administrative password in the security dialog." with icon note
        end tell
        set UI elements enabled to true
        if UI elements enabled is false then return "User Cancelled"
        delay 1
    end if

    tell process "System Preferences"
        click button "Network" of scroll area 1 of window "System Preferences"

        --Creating VPN (CU Primary) interface
        tell window "Network"
            click button "Add Service"
            delay 1
        end tell

        tell sheet 1 of window "Network"

            click pop up button 1
            click menu item "VPN" of menu 1 of pop up button 1
            delay 1
            click pop up button 2
            click menu item "Cisco IPSec" of menu 1 of pop up button 2
            set focused of text field 1 to true
            keystroke "a" using command down
            keystroke vpnname
            click button "Create"
            delay 1
        end tell

        --Entering server / account details
        tell group 1 of window "Network"
            click checkbox "Show VPN status in menu bar"
            set focused of text field 3 to true
            keystroke vpnserver
            set focused of text field 1 to true
            keystroke vpnusername
            click button 2 --pressing "Advanced…" button
            delay 1
        end tell

        --Entering "Advanced…" details
        tell sheet 1 of window "Network"
            activate
            set focused of text field 2 to true
            keystroke vpnsecret
            set focused of text field 1 to true
            keystroke groupname
            click button "OK"
            delay 1
        end tell

        -- Apply all changes
        tell window "Network"
            click button "Apply"
            delay 1
        end tell

        tell application "System Preferences"
            quit saving yes
        end tell

    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it will work but if any of the key strokes are going into applescript just run the

tell application "application name here"

activate

end tell

before the keystrokes that are being put into apple script then it will focus on the window you have told it to

Sorry for the lack of code snippet I am new to this forum and I'm not sure how to use it properly